# Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> VStack<Button<Text>>' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'

Tags: swiftui

My error message is: Cannot convert value of type 'Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> VStack>' to expected argument type '(_) -> _''

I know the error bit of the code is where I'm using 'array[index].documentID' in call to getMedia but I don't know why or how to resolve.

Please could you help?

Here is my code for the view:

```
struct weekDataList: View {
let weekDataF = weekDataFunc()
@ObservedObject var MainViews = MainView()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(array.count, id: \.self) { index in
            VStack{
                Button(action: {MainViews.getMedia(documentId: array[index].documentID)}) 
                               {Text(array[index].startDate + "-" + array[index].endDate)}
            }
        }.position(x:100,y:-100)
    }
}
```

Comment: The `MainViews.getMedia` returns View, but it is not allowed to use SwiftUI View in action block. Would you describe what you try to achieve?

Comment: I'm not returning anything from MainViews.getMedia. It only accepts one parameter and I want to run some functions when the button is clicked

Comment: Would you show `MainView` code then? Or provide minimum testable standalone demo, because provided snapshot has many dependent unavailable components that generate a lot of compiler error by themselves.

Comment: Right now, this is what MainView looks like. It's not much, I was just testing how to get the button to run some different functions when clicked:

`class MainView: ObservableObject{
        @Published var updateView: Bool = false
        
        func getMedia(documentId: Int) {
            print("test")
        }
    
        func chunkVideos() {
            videosChunked = videos.chunked(into:3)
        }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by code reading, because, as I commented, snapshot is not compilable

```
ForEach(0..<array.count) { index in
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ should be range and no id for indexes
```